# Clone Link and wrap new Element

Tags: jquery

I clone an Href and wrap it to an DIV. But the Problem is, when I have multiple Elements, the second Element becomes the same Link.
I know the each Function, but how can I use this Function?

```js
var link = $('.image-title').clone().empty().prop('outerHTML');
$('.text-hover').wrap(link);
```

```html
<div class="ref-wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="image.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="borscheid"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
            <a href="iamge2.jpg" data-gallery="borscheid"></a>
            <div class="text-hover">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            
<div class="ref-wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="image2_1.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="botel"><img src="image2_1.jpg"></a>
            <a href="iamge2_2.jpg" data-gallery="botel"></a>
            <div class="text-hover">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrsaidy/uj44vybL/)

That is what i want:

```
<div class="ref-wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="image.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="borscheid"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
            <a href="iamge2.jpg" data-gallery="borscheid"></a>
            <a href="image.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="borscheid"><div class="text-hover">content</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ref-wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="image2_1.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="botel"><img src="image2_1.jpg"></a>
            <a href="iamge2_2.jpg" data-gallery="botel"></a>
            <a href="image2_1.jpg" class="image-title" data-gallery="botel"><div class="text-hover">content</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first Href wrap to the Div "text-hover".

Comment: You've described a problem, but not explained exactly what you're trying to achieve...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$('.image-title').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).clone().empty().prop('outerHTML');
    $(this).siblings(".text-hover").wrap(link);
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pm6hubk/)